# R: Extract first number despite irregular delimiter from a junk data

Tags: r, regex, digits, grepl

I am working on a dataframe `df` that has thousands of rows of junk data in which the first number is to be extracted despite irregular delimiter:

```
dummy_numbers = c("70210813000 70210862354",
"(234) 641-9690", "ren  23465726375 Finney",
"234 0225 7583 ALT 031 026 66542", "omega",
"(034) 319-6427", "(034)3263802", "(034)3128548",
"Mat: 030791272113 / 03040752983")

df <- data.frame(dummy_numbers)

> df
                    dummy_numbers
1         70210813000 70210862354
2                  (234) 641-9690
3         ren  23465726375 Finney
4 234 0225 7583 ALT 031 026 66542
5                           omega
6                  (034) 319-6427
7                    (034)3263802
8                    (034)3128548
9 Mat: 030791272113 / 03040752983
```

Expected result is:

```
> df
          dummy_numbers
1         70210813000
2         2346419690
3         23465726375
4         23402257583
5         NA
6         0343196427
7         0343263802
8         0343128548
9         030791272113
```

The idea of removing letters, punctuation, spaces, dash and all non-numeric did not yield desired result. I think it is due to inability to deal with irregular delimiters.

```
> df %>% dplyr::mutate(dummy_numbers = gsub("[- ./)(+]|[a-zA-Z]*:?","", dummy_numbers))
            dummy_numbers
1  7021081300070210862354
2              2346419690
3             23465726375
4  2340225758303102666542
5                        
6              0343196427
7              0343263802
8              0343128548
9 03079127211303040752983
```

The idea of employing `str_first_number()` function from the `strex` package did not also yield desired result.

```
library(strex)
> df %>% dplyr::mutate(dummy_numbers = str_first_number(dummy_numbers))
  dummy_numbers
1   70210813000
2           234
3   23465726375
4           234
5            NA
6            34
7            34
8            34
9   30791272113
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but you have many different phone number types in there, including some non standard numbers which are not 10 digit US phone numbers.  If you can normalize this data at the source before you bring it into R, then please do so.

Comment: Yes, I also think there should be some data cleaning prior to the extraction. Stringi's function gives better results but still fails. `stri_extract_first_regex(df$dummy_numbers, "[0-9]+")`

Answer (score 3):

You can split the problem in two, based on the examples you have given.

First work on the strings with no alpha characters and no brackets or minus.

Then do the others. Not sure though if this holds true for all values you have in your data set. You may have to add more rules and use `case_when` or similar.

```
library(stringr)

data.frame(dummy_numbers=
  ifelse(!grepl("[[:alpha:]()-]", df$dummy_numbers),
    str_extract(df$dummy_numbers, "[[:digit:]]+"),
    trimws(str_extract(gsub("[ ()-]","", 
             df$dummy_numbers), "[[:digit:]]+"))))
  dummy_numbers
1   70210813000
2    2346419690
3   23465726375
4   23402257583
5          <NA>
6    0343196427
7    0343263802
8    0343128548
9  030791272113
```

Comment: Many thanks. Your code is a significant step towards the desired result, though this does not hold true for all values in the data set. Other rules still need to be added